# How buffering works in GeoPandas?

Tags: buffer, geopandas, shapely, parameters

I try to add a buffer on a set of lines via the `buffer` attribute of geopandas.

But by testing on a simple case (see code below) I realize that the size of the buffer is not kept according to the points latitude.

The buffer build at point A is well 2° but at point B is only 0.35° (checked via QGIS).

Could someone please explain to me how this buffer works under geopandas?

And if you have a solution to generate a buffer that is robust to the change of latitude I'm interested!

```py
import geopandas as gpd

from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

# 2 points creation
A = Point(0.0, 0.0)
B = Point(0.0, 80.0)

# Linestring creation
lines_geom = LineString([A, B])
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} # WGS84 CRS
lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[lines_geom])       

# Buffer generation
lines_buffer_1deg = lines.buffer(1.0, resolution=1)
print(lines_buffer_1deg)

lines_buffer_1deg.to_file("test.shp")
```

As proposed in the comment I also tried with a projected CRS, EPSG:3395 world mercator with the same result (see code below and caption from QGIS).

```py
import geopandas as gpd

from shapely.geometry import mapping, Polygon, LineString, Point

# 2 points creation
A = Point(0.0,0.0)
B = Point(0.0,9000000.0)

# Linestring creation
lines_geom = LineString([A,B])
crs = {'init': 'epsg:3395'} 
lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[lines_geom])       

# Buffer generation
lines_buffer_100km = lines.buffer(100000.0,resolution=1)
print(lines_buffer_100km)

lines_buffer_100km.to_file("test.shp")
```

EPSG:3395 around 0° latitude:
[image: EPSG:3395 at around 0° latitude]

EPSG:3395 around 62° latitude:
[image: EPSG:3395 around 62° latitude]

Comment: pushing the question down the stack, GeoPandas uses shapely for this operation, so the question really is what is shapely doing?

Comment: You have "World mercator projection" written beside a command that specifies your EPSG as 4326. One of these is wrong (either the comment or the code). Shapely doesn't care about your units or projection at all, so my guess is that your issue lies in your projection. It's almost always a bad idea to buffer shapes that are in degree coordinates (i.e. 4326). Convert them to a projected CRS in meters first.

Comment: @Jon - I, too, was going to comment about using a projected CRS as well until I tried his example in QGIS in EPSG:4326. I was slightly surprised that it produced the result he was looking for - a buffer a uniform 2 degrees wide running from the equator to 80 degrees north. I can imagine use cases where this is the desired result.

Comment: Yes you right @Jon about the CRS, it's a copying error and edit the question. I also tried with projected EPSG:3395 and have the same result (see the new question editing).

Comment: @LLaves As it should. Like I said, shapely doesn't care about your units or projection so if you ask for a buffer of "2", you'll get a buffer of "2." The reason it's a bad idea (usually) to buffer in degrees is that your buffer width/length will not be the same everywhere as the length of a degree of longitude shrinks towards the poles, or put another way, 2 degrees longitude is a much smaller length in Alaska than at the equator.

Comment: @Jon as a mariner 2 degrees is always 2 degress, this is its representation on projected chart that will change depending the  latitude of your point. That's why my first test was on this CRS. But as shown above I have the same error with projected data.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating your buffer in an unprojected (geographic) CRS EPSG:4326, not "world mercator" as commented in your script.

Your buffers are generated correctly (if it can be said that using degrees as a measurement is "correct"...), with 2 degree width at all latitudes.  However you are viewing them in EPSG:3857 a projected coordinate system known as "Web Mercator" or "Pseudo-Mercator" so they appear squashed at higher latitudes.

Basically, you are buffering in one coordinate system, if you display and measure in that coordinate system, you will get the expected buffer width. If you display/measure in a different coordinate system, you'll get a different answer.

Below are a couple of screenshots of the same shapefile (EPSG:4326 & 3395) output by your code, but using different CRS in QGIS to visualise/measure.

**EPSG:4326**

[image]

**EPSG:3857**

[image]

**EPSG:3395**

[image]

Note that using EPSG:3857 to do any sort of measurement is a *bad idea*. The Web Mercator projection is designed for one thing only, chopping up the globe into 256x256 tiles for web mapping.  From an [Esri article](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-enterprise/mapping/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/):

> The modified Mercator projection used by Google, Bing, and ArcGIS
> Online is not designed to minimize distortion at all. Instead, it was
> engineered for convenience in working with cached map tiles. This
> projection fit the entire globe (well, most of the latitudes anyway)
> into a square area that could be covered by 256 x 256 pixel tiles. The
> projection sacrifices some accuracy because it is based on a perfect
> sphere (the earth is better approximated by a spheroid), but the
> biggest problem is the heavy vertical and horizontal stretching at
> extreme latitudes. This is evident from the enormous dimensions of
> Greenland and Antarctica relative to land masses closer to the
> Equator:
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You're right, it's a copying error in the commentary. I edit the question. But still strange to me, with the same CRS chosen in QGIS I can't have 2 degrees at the top polygon.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but if you look at the new editing above I'm working with the same CRS EPSG:3395 for building and viewing the shapefile. And stil have trouble with the EPSG;4326 in QGIS that you didn't have (same CRS used for building and viewing).

Comment: I've no idea what you're doing then, see my edit. I'm getting exactly as expected when buffering using your code and displaying in 3395...

Comment: Is it possible to have access your version number of geopandas and shapely? I tried with another SIG (global mapper) and have the same trouble. 
I also tried to build the buffer of 2 different point (lat/long 0.0 and lat 80.0 long 0.0), and have the same buffer.area information...

Comment: shapely == '1.6.4', geopandas ==  '0.7.0'

Comment: Thanks, I have the same. I will try to understand why I have this difference. Did you think is it possible to send me your shapefile generate (by ftp transfer for example) to test it?

Comment: @Robin Not sure this makes a difference, but in QGIS under Properties, there are some options to set the ellipsoid for measurements. I would think that's by default the same for everyone, but might be worth looking at. Mine is set to EPSG:7019.

Comment: @Jon, Yes I test it and have the same ellipsoid (EPSG:7019) in my QGIS Properties.

Comment: @user2856 If soure GeoDataFrame has geographic projection, and I want to apply metric buffer (e.g. 10m) should GDF be first (before buffering) reprojected to projected coordinate system? I mean reprojection is not done in background.